# What is the minimum number of matches that can make all four regular polygon pairs?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

There is a box of matches of the same length. I want to make each pair of equilateral triangles, squares, regular pentagons, and regular hexagons using all the matches in a box. If you have 11 matches in a box, you can use all 11 matches if you make 3 matches for an equilateral triangle and 8 matches for an square.
For pairs of equilateral triangles and equilateral triangles, you can make six matches for an equilateral triangles and 4 matches for a regular pentagon. However, an equilateral triangle and a regular hexagon pair cannot be made from 11 matches. So eleven matches can't make all pairs of the above four regular polygons. What is the minimum number of matches that can make all four regular polygon pairs?

Actually 36 is the answer, but I want know the procedure to get answer. Please give me some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of matches, $N$, must be the least positive integer which can be expressed as $3a+4b$ (for triangles and squares), as $3a+6b$ (for triangles and hexagons), etc.

It is useful to note that, from $4a+6b$, $N$ must be even and, from $3a+6b$, $N$ must be a multiple of 3. So $N$ is a multiple of 6. Then, from $5a+6b$, $a$ must be a multiple of 6 and so $N$ has to be at least 36. All that remains is to check that 36 satisfies each possibility.